# PHP output buffering variable

Tags: php, variables, output-buffering

Is it possible to use a POST variable on the buffered script? The code is the following

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$someVar= $_POST["var"];

ob_start();
require "someScript.php?var=" . $someVar; // instead of passing through GET, is there a way to use the $someVar directly?
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output;
?>
```

Note: I've already tried to access $someVar directly from someScript but without success. For that is why I'm asking. Thanks

EDIT: Possible someScript.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    require_once("BD.php");
    require_once("json/json_header.php");
    require_once("tools.php");
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    $BD = new BDInfo(); 


    function encodeIDs($id1,$id2){

        // doesn't matter
    }

    $response = array("errorCode" => 0, "errorDesc" => "No Error");


    if(isset($someVar)){
        try{
            $link = mysqli_connect($BD->BDServer, $BD->BDUsername, $BD->BDPassword);

            if( !$link )
                throw new Exception( "..." );

            if( !mysqli_select_db($link, $BD->BDDatabase) )
                throw new Exception( "..." );

            $SQL="SELECT (...) us.VAR='" . $someVar . "';";

            $RS = mysqli_query($link,$SQL);
            if($RS && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($RS)){
                // process query result
            }
            else
            {
                $response["errorCode"]=4;    
                $response["errorDesc"]="Error descr";   
            }
            mysqli_close($link);

        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $response["errorCode"]=1;
            $response["errorDesc"]="Database Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }else{
        $response["errorCode"]=2;
        $response["errorDesc"]="Invalid Parameters";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I get Invalid Parameters, showing that isset($var) failed

Comment: Have you tried it out? What have you come with so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - include() file not working when variables are put in url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301552/php-include-file-not-working-when-variables-are-put-in-url)

Comment: @sandeep, what i'm trying to do is to use a variable on an imported script. I thought I made it clear

Comment: I think @Yotaware guessed best what you are trying to do, so give that answer a try...

Comment: @jose Please post the code in `someScript.php`, too.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for down voting my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$someVar` is already available to you in `someScript.php`. You should not use a query string to do transfer it.

If you want to avoid modifying `someScript.php` for some reason then you can do this:

```
$_GET['var'] = $someVar;
```

Or just this:

```
$_GET['var'] = $_POST['var'];
```

Comment: I can't access $someVar on someScript.php. I've tried just now.

Comment: It should work. Try to setup a much simpler example and see if it works then. See [here](http://uoco.net/d/dev/include/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you include a script with `include` or `require`, that script has access to all variables in scope at the inclusion site. In your example, you can access `$someVar` directly from `someScript.php` (you could also directly access `$_POST` or anything else).

Comment: But not with that output buffer he uses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Since `require()` works similar to [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), the included file inherits the variable scope.

From the manual:

```
"When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the 
line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the 
calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. 
However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global 
scope."
```

Imagine an include (or require) as that the included code *replaces* the line `include ...`.